# The proof of chain rule using a junk term

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, chain-rule

I am looking into understanding the proofs for the Chain Rule. I came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BicyN84QYbQ&t=49s) video by Dr. Peyam on youtube.

When proving the chain rule he states that:

$$\frac{g(y+\widetilde{h})-g(y)}{\widetilde{h}} = g'(y) + \sigma(\widetilde{h})$$
Where he refers to $\sigma$ as a junk term. And later he says that $\sigma \rightarrow 0$ as $\widetilde{h} \rightarrow 0$. Why can one use this alternative description of the derivative and why does the **junk term** become $0$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: (I think you're missing a squiggle on the $h$ in the denominator.)

Comment: why use $\tilde h$ instead of the simpler $h?$

Comment: I just defined it in the same way as Dr. Peyam did in the video, he did it because he was using the simpler h in a different equation. I could have just used $h$ as well. I will fix the denominator, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common and useful way to handle proofs involving derivatives. We know that
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f'(x)
$$
If we define a funciton $\sigma(h)$ (I have seen $\varepsilon(h)$ used as function name for the same thing) as
$$
\sigma(h) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - f'(x)
$$
then
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\sigma(h) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - f'(x) = 0
$$
which proves why the "junk term" goes to zero.

Put in words, the "junk term" is the difference between the derivative and the approximation given by the difference quotiont. As $h$ gets smaller, the approximation gets better.

Bonus: It works the other way around too! If
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = g(x) + \sigma(h)
$$
and $\lim_{h\to0}\sigma(h)=0$, then $g(x)=f'(x)$, which is equally useful for making proofs.

EDIT. By the way, $\sigma$ is really a function of both $x$ and $h$, but we tend to work with a fixed $x$ (or $y$ in your case), so we don't write $\sigma(x,h)$.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. Do you know if there are any textbooks which explain how one came upon using such a solution?

Comment: Not in particular, but any introductory book on real analysis/calculus would be a good bet. You should not think of this as a very clever trick, but rather as equivalent to the usual definition. It is just often easier to work with, especially when multiple functions are involved.